# error con charts js en react

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

Estoy intentando usar charts.js en react pero tengo algunos errores, encontré algo que mencionaba que posiblemente era la versión de la librería porque la versión 3 en adelante estaba presentado fallos; así que instale la v2.9.4 de charts.js y efectivamente el error desapareció pero apareció otro:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'chart.js/auto' in '/home/juan/Desktop/newnet/client/node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist'
```

He investigado por internet y no encontrado documentacion sobre este error.

Comment: Según vi en varios sitios `npm install--save chart.js@2.9.4` arregla el problema. Inténtalo.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez me parece que es lo que acaba de decir que hizo ...

Comment: valida si charts.js esta en este path: ***/home/juan/Desktop/newnet/client/node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist***

Comment: Para usar char.js con react necesita solo dos cosas, Instalarla librería de react para manejar char.js con `npm install --save react-chartjs-2` e instalar una versión de char.js < 3 con el comando `npm install --save chart.js@2.9.4` . Con eso instalado correctamente no debe haber problemas. Los problemas aparecen si instala una de las últimas versiones ya que no son compatibles con react todavía.

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Hola amigo resulta que revise y ese charts.js no se encuentra en esa ruta pero no se como colocar el arvhivo en esa ruta.

Comment: esto es lo que dice la documentacion: **You can download the latest version of Chart.js on GitHub .

If you download or clone the repository, you must build Chart.js to generate the dist files. Chart.js no longer comes with prebuilt release versions, so an alternative option to downloading the repo is strongly advised.**

Comment: y estos son los archivos que te hacen falta: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js

Comment: se supone que al abrir npm debes estas ubicado en este directorio para hacer la instalacion: **/home/juan/Desktop/newnet/client/node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist** si estabas en otro directorio no lo va a instalar donde debe ser, pasa lo mismo que con composer ...